# Tensorial calculus: A question about free and summed indices

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, list-manipulation

I have to start with a full disclosure that I'm new to Mathematica, so this might be easy to resolve in a way that I don't know.

I have to implement a triple contraction of an order three tensor

$$d^{imn} = \sum t^{ij}t^{mp}t^{nq}d_{jpq}$$

where the sum is over $j,p,q=0,...,23$.

I started trying something like this

```
 dup= Array[s, {24, 24, 24}, {0, 0, 0};
 Do[ dup[i, m, n] = Sum[tinv[[i, j]]*tinv[[m, p]]*tinv[[n, q]]*down[[j, p, q]], ?  ] , {j, 
      0, 23}, {p, 0, 23}, {q, 0, 23}];
```

But clearly I have a problem on how to implement the sum. Does anybody have a clue on how could I implement this triple sum?

Comment: Could you please consider changing the title such that it describes the question a bit better? An example would be "A question about free and summed indices" or "Distinguishing free and summed indices" or something to that effect. Just a suggestion

Comment: ok will do promptly

Comment: Many thanks. A quick explanation on why I suggested this change. It would probably be more beneficial for other users as well who might face similar difficulties. I am hoping that you were not offended by the suggestion.

Comment: Have a look at [TensorContract](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorContract.html?q=TensorContract).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) for the free indices and [`Sum`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html) to do the summation in the following manner:

```
dd[xx_, yy_, zz_] := 
 Table[Sum[
   t[i, j] t[m, p] t[n, q] d[j, p, q], {j, 0, 23}, {p, 0, 23}, {q, 0, 
    23}], {i, 0, xx}, {m, 0, yy}, {n, 0, zz}]
```